# Magento 2, include plaintext version of html mail

Tags: magento2, mail

How can I include a plaintext version of my html mail in Magento using the transportbuilder?

Comment: explain in brief

Comment: Something like this but we use the transportbuilder : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267840/sending-an-email-with-php-plain-text-and-html

Comment: I could either be a way to add the plaintext manually somehow or automaticly - im just so clueless about how to send both in same mail in magento